# How to distinguish normal white space characters with other white space characters

Tags: java, jdbc, relational-database, rdbms

For example:
In MySQL. the data type `Text`,
If we have a column defined as `Text` in a MySQL table, when to retrieve value of this column in JDBC, you get the value with excess trailing spaces, you can call `String#trim(),` but if such column is intended to accept space characters (**hit space key when input**). What can I do then?

MySQL Text is only for example, please consider other similar data types in other database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, your question should be worded as: "How can I get rid of trailing spaces that my RDBMS puts into my fields?"

The answer is simple: never declare fixed-width columns such as CHAR(10) or NCHAR(10). These types were invented back in the dark ages of relational databases, and the only reason they still exist is for backwards compatibility with legacy systems.

Always use variable length width columns: VARCHAR, NVARCHAR, TEXT.

Now, if your columns *are* of variable width, and yet your fields contain trailing spaces, this means that you have converted your table from some older table which had fixed-width columns. There is nothing you can do other than read all of your fields, apply `String.Trim()` to them, and write them back to the database.

Answer (score 1):

`String.trim()` will not delete white space inside the string.

Comment: oops..Francis Upton beats me.

Answer (score 0):

I think `String.trim()` does what you want, it deletes leading and trailing whitespace. The whitespace that is inside of the string will stay. Is this what you are asking?

Comment: no, if user input 'ABC ' I want to keep the trailing spaces user inputted but wipe out all the trailing spaces filled by mysql.

Comment: I don't think you can distinguish whitespace added by MySQL from whitespace that was entered by the user (I'm not sure why MySQL would add whitespace in a VARCHAR).

Comment: Also, if the trailing spaces filled by MySQL is same thing as hitting space key, then this question have no answer.

Comment: MySQL does't add whitespace in a VARCHAR, but Text.

Comment: sorry for my bad english, make you hard to understand what I am talking about :D

Comment: Your English is good enough, you said `Text`. However, I don't see [in the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/blob.html) where whitespace is added by MySQL to the Text type. And of course the text type allows trailing or leading whitespace. It will pad with whitespace when doing an index comparison, but should not return that value that's padded.